# Help with conditional probability?

Tags: probability

I've got to show that:

$$\mathbb{P} (A | A \cap B) = \frac{ \mathbb{P}(A)}{ \mathbb{P} (A \cap B)}$$

I'm not sure how to get to this.

Surely the probability of A occurring given A and B occurs is 1?

Or, by the equation...

$$\mathbb{P} (A | A \cap B) = \frac{ \mathbb{P} (A \cap A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P} (A \cap B)}$$

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing something, you're completely correct, and the question is wrong.

$$\mathbb P(A|A\cap B) \equiv \frac{\mathbb P(A\cap (A\cap B))}{\mathbb P(A\cap B)} = \frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(A\cap B)} = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Yet another explanation is that the typo(s) in question are that $\cup$ was replaced
by $\cap$ (or an `u` in `\cup` got changed to an `a` to give `\cap` for it is certainly
true that
$$P(A \mid A\cup B) = \frac{P(A \cap (A \cup B))}{P(A \cup B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(A \cup B)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think, it must be a *typo*. It is also well possible that $\Bbb P(A)>\Bbb P(A\cap B)$, so the right hand side is $>1$.

The similar equation what we have is
$$\Bbb P(A\cap B\mid A)=\frac{\Bbb P(A\cap B)}{\Bbb P(A)}\,.$$

Probably the author made a correction note to this exercise to '*exchange the terms*', but later when he executed these notes, exchanged the terms in the fractions..